# Error when I echo HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, html

This script errors and I can't find where, I know it's in the $homeRandom section yet I can't seem to work out what it is.

Is there a good way of printing large amounts of HTML in PHP?

```html
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM Products";
 $resulta = $conn->query($sqla);

 if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) {

     $homePage = '';

     while($rowa = $resulta->fetch_assoc()) {
         $nav = '<li><a href="'.$rowa['UrlPage'].'">'.$rowa['Name'].'</a></li>';
         $homeRandom = '
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
           <img src="./content/images/homepage/'.$rowa['ImageName'].'.jpg" alt="">
           <div class="caption">
               <h4 class="pull-right">'.$rowa['Price'].'</h4>
               <h4><a href="'.$rowa['UrlPage'].'">'.$rowa['Name'].'</a>
               </h4>
               <p>'.$rowa['Description'].'</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>'

         $homePage = $homePage . $homeRandom; 
     }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Other than the missed semicolon?

Comment: @JohnConde The page is just blank works fine if I switch $homePage = $homePage . $homeRandom; to $nav = $homePage . $homeRandom; So i know its the $homeRandom part.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Jesus I really am tired... Many Thanks!

Comment: </div>';
$homePage = $homePage . $homeRandom; you are forgetting a semi colon. after div

Comment: if you think the error is about that part you can try this $homePage .= $homeRandom;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing semi colon, and seemingly a missing brace, but that could just be the way you've copied and pasted.

```
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM Products";
    $resulta = $conn->query($sqla);

    if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) {

        $homePage = '';

        while($rowa = $resulta->fetch_assoc()) {
            $nav = '<li><a href="'.$rowa['UrlPage'].'">'.$rowa['Name'].'</a></li>';
            $homeRandom = '
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="./content/images/homepage/'.$rowa['ImageName'].'.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4 class="pull-right">'.$rowa['Price'].'</h4>
                        <h4><a href="'.$rowa['UrlPage'].'">'.$rowa['Name'].'</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p>'.$rowa['Description'].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>'; //<-- missing in yours

            $homePage = $homePage . $homeRandom; 
        }
} //<-- also missing in yours, but could just be a copy 
  //paste missed the last }
```

Additionally, you should start reading the error log, as it'll tell you good info which you can use to identify where the issue is.
ie
"unexpected '$homePage' (T_VARIABLE)"
Something unexpected usually means it was expecting something before it.

You should also use a good IDE, Netbeans, PHPStorm etc, as they return all sorts of info about your code, such as underlined for errors etc

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a good way of printing large amounts of HTML in PHP?**

Yes there is, you can make use of opening and closing php tags and improve readability by using the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
<?php if (condition) : ?>

<!-- HTML goes here -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Or simply with a normal if statement:

```
<?php if (condition) { ?>

<!-- HTML goes here -->

<?php } ?>
```

Or the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) method:

```
echo <<<EOT
<p>My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.</p>
<p>Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.</p>
<p>This should print a capital 'A': \x41</p>
EOT;
```